# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate - Missing C++ Projects Templates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I installed fresh install of my `Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013` and launched it. I then went to `FILE -> New -> Project` and wanted to create new C++ project. However, there is no option for creating such project now (I know it was there before, on my second laptop). I restarted installer and pressed repair, but nothing changed. I also tried to uninstall it and then install it back again. I also have `MSVC2015 RC` and I can create C++ Projects there. During an installation I was asked if I want to install certain features as well and I did install everything that was offered.

This is how my `New Project` looks like. [image: New Project Window]

What is going on in there? Did I forget to install something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with VS2012, some time ago. I've solved **installing again**. Not sure if VS2013 makes you configure if you want to install "C++ stuff" during the installation process.

Comment: Actually, you can't choose not to install C++